# Editing individual weights and biases in a layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a project in which I need to edit individual weights and biases.

Is there any way to actually get access to the layers weights and biases so I can edit them manually?
from `tf.layers.dense()`

So far I have created my own model and stored the biases outside like so:

```
for _ in range(population_size):
    hidden_layer.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([11, 20])))
    output_layer.append(tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([20, 9])))
population.append([hidden_layer, output_layer])
```

I am then trying to feed population into the model using feed dict. It's turning out to be a real hell because I cannot feed them into the models because of the shapes of the Variables are not the same.

Is there any native support for getting the weights from the dense layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the keras doc:](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/)

> All Keras layers have a number of methods in common:
>
> ```
> layer.get_weights(): returns the weights of the layer as a list of Numpy arrays.
> layer.set_weights(weights): sets the weights of the layer from a list of Numpy arrays (with the same shapes as the output of get_weights).
> ```

You can easily access all layers inside your model with `yourmodel.layers`.

Comment: Hey, sorry I never worked with keras before only pure tensorflow but I thought keras migh have the solution. Do you think there is a way I could feed the weights into a model so I can edit all the weights from multiple different layers at once? I want to run the edits in a tensorflow session so i can do the edits in parallel so its faster. Otherwise it takes way too long.

Comment: You can also call `yourmodel.get_weights()``and `yourmodel.set_weights(weights)`. This will return/take a list of numpy arrays (Be careful it's not one numpy array per layer). So you can easily take all weights with one call, feed it into your tf session, get the new weights with the same shape and assign them back to your model.